# How to search an api that does not have a search page?

Tags: javascript, json, api, web-scraping, search

Say, I have the api `api.example.com`, and it has a page under `api.example.com/view/${id}` that takes an id and returns json data like so:

```json
{
  title: "foobar",
  id: 34102
}
```

The api does not have a search page.
The possible ids starts from `00001` to `99999`. How can I search for "foobar" and get back 34102?
The only option I can think of is storing all that data through web scraping then searching in it. But sending 100000 requests would most likely get my IP banned.

Thanks.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if the website providing the API does not also provide an API with a keyword search, you won't be able to find it by that parameter. They are their API routes and they can handle the logic and parameters as they choose, so if they don't want you searching by a title, you're out of luck.

Keep in mind that your alternative solution is not something that you should do -- You should not hit someone's API with 1k+ requests.